# Increase protected range

Tags: time, range, locking

How can I increase protected ranges (cells) with time automatically? I mean after input data at row 1 , I wanna lock it at specified time automatically.And so row 2,3,...  . Only me,editor not on locked but on collaborators.

Comment: What program/software are you talking about? Please [edit] to add a tag for it.

Comment: please tag the specific programming language